# Do I need to connect the jumper pins in a SATA hard drive to anything?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard, sata, chromebook

I am looking at replacing the 16GB SSD on my Chromebook (C710-2856) with a bigger, maybe a little faster SSD so that my laptop has room for more Linux stuff and maybe Windows 8 if I can find the drivers for a similar laptop.

I am looking at new SSDsand trying to find a cheap but decent one, and in the time being I have an old 250GB HDD with slow read/write (5400 RPM, ~40 MB/s read and write) that I would like to install just for laughs. The 250 GB hard drive is 2.5" SATA, and is about double the length of the current SSD. I have examined the internals of a C710-2834 before, which is very similar, and there is plenty of room for longer drives such as this one.

Looking at this, I originally thought that I should be able to install this hard drive.

However, I noticed that there is, along with the normal SATA pins, 4 extra pins that I cannot identify:

SATA_power________________________SATA_data______?????

l_l_l_l_l_l_l_l_l_l_l_l_l_l_l_______________l_l_l_l_l_l_l______l_l_l_l

Looking at some diagrams of this particular hard drive (WD2500BEVS) these pins are sometimes referred to as "jumper pins", and some diagrams suggest that connecting certain pins changes the speed limitations of the hard drive. ***Assuming I do not want to mess around with these pins, is it OK to leave them unconnected to anything?*** The connector on the motherboard interfacing with SATA does not have any section to connect to this, but the drive will definitely fit. (I broke a C710-2834 a month ago, and I held on to some parts in case they could be useful. I took out the SATA connectr since the motherboard was fried and it fits perfectly in the 250 GB HDD.)

Not too long ago, I asked a question that may be relevant to this one about figuring out if any particular SSD will fit:
[previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/843299/how-can-i-determine-if-a-certain-hard-drive-will-fit-my-chromebook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ignore these pins. They are used to force the controller chip working under sata1 mode (legacy) if your HDD  is sata2 or above.

Another possible answer for these pins is TTL connector. Used for low-level communication. For example: [Fixing a Seagate 7200.11 Hard Drive](https://web.archive.org/web/20141222110518/https://sites.google.com/site/seagatefix/Home).

[image: pins]